# nginx proxy rewrite not matching

Tags: url-rewriting, proxy, nginx

I'm setting Nginx to forward requests to several backend services using proxy_pass

A few of them I have to add rewrite rules to strip the folder off, however for this particular service, the rewrite rule isn't working on styles/images. Any tips?

```
~$ tail /var/log/nginx/error.log
2012/02/09 10:57:19 [error] 4103#0: *10 open() "/var/www/images/blank.gif" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 203.xxx.xxx.xxx, server: example.net, request: "GET /images/blank.gif HTTP/1.1", host: "example.net", referrer: "https://example.net/hp/"

~$ cat /etc/nginx/proxy-control.conf; 
proxy_connect_timeout   59s;
proxy_send_timeout      600;
proxy_read_timeout      600;
proxy_buffer_size       64k;
proxy_buffers           16 32k;
proxy_pass_header       Set-Cookie;
proxy_hide_header       Vary;

proxy_busy_buffers_size         64k;
proxy_temp_file_write_size      64k;

proxy_set_header        Accept-Encoding         '';
proxy_ignore_headers    Cache-Control           Expires;
proxy_set_header        Referer                 $http_referer;
proxy_set_header        Host                    $host;
proxy_set_header        Cookie                  $http_cookie;
proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP               $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Host        $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Server      $host;
proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For         $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;

proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Ssl         on;
proxy_set_header        Authorization           '';

proxy_redirect         http://example.net/ /;
proxy_redirect         https://example.net/ /;


~$ tail /etc/nginx/services.conf;
location /hp {
    rewrite           ^/hp$          https://example.net/hp/           permanent;                                                       $
    rewrite           /hp/(.*)      /$1                             break;

    proxy_pass        http://192.168.1.2/;
    include           proxy-control.conf;
    include           auth-basic.conf;
}
```

chrome errors;

```
https://example.net/images/blank.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
https://example.net/images/final-hp-login_1x11.gif Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Comment: I just wanted to say the English NGINX support forum is incredibly helpful and you'll often get a quick response. I'm not saying this site isn't helpful, but just for really tech specific requests on NGINX I typically post in there as well as server fault

Answer (score 1):

I think your settings are incorrect. When there is a request to `https://example.net/images/blank.gif` it is sent to `http://192.168.1.2/images/blank.gif` and there will be a 404. Your two rewrites do not match, of course, because this request does not begin with /hp. Maybe you want `proxy_pass http://192.168.1.2/hp`?

Comment: the request for the image originated from the /hp/ page. URLs requested on the /hp/ need to be rewritten to include /hp/ in them.  This rewriting works on other services

Comment: In any case, https://example.net/images/blank.gif won't work, as it does not begin with /hp (this conf is for example.net, isn't it?). Only  https://example.net/hp/images/blank.gif *may* work?